# Previewing issue

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, admin

I just installed Magento through my quick installs in my cPanel. I have set up the Shop and added a couple products but when I view my Shop on line the categories and products don't show. Is there some sort of 'switch' I need to throw to view my shop?
Shop url: www.kancerkidz.org/shop/
Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Double check to make sure that your product is assign to a category www.kancerkidz.org/shop/index.php/silk-fabric-flexible-bangle-bracelet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to check if all of your products are on stock and have quantity more than 0.

In the case of the categories you should check if they have products assigned to them.

Go to System -> Manage Stores -> Store Name -  click on your store name and see if your root category are set there, if are not, so, set it.

Comment: I have 3 categories and the 2 products are assigned to one of the categories. They both have 50+ stock

Comment: The categories that you create are inside of the default category?

Comment: I don't have a 'default' category. I have 3 categories: jewelry, t-shirts, accessories. both products are in the jewelry categoty

Comment: So, what is your Root category? You have one, right?

Comment: Go to System -> Manage Stores -> Store Name   click on your store name and see if your root category are set there

Comment: I guess not ;) I have 3 categories that I created. No 'default' category. Should I creat a 'default' category, and place my 3 categories in it?

Comment: root category is 'awareness jewelry items'

Comment: Go to System -> Manage Stores -> Store Name click on your store name and see if your root category are set there. Set the Awareness Jewerly itens on the Root Category field.

Comment: I got it! I deleted the 3 categories, created a 'default' category, then added the 3 categories to the default category as 'sub categories'. now the category is listed. Now I'll have to re-add the products. THANK YOU!!